# Necessary to find an estimator's probability distribution before calculating its expectation?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Where $X_{1}, X_{2}, \dots X_{n}$ is an iid distribution with pdf given by:

\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\theta}x^{1-\theta} \qquad &\text{If $0 \leq x \leq 1$} \\[5 pt]
0 \qquad &Otherwise
\end{cases}

It can be shown using the M.L.E for estimator inference that $\theta$ is given by:
$$\theta = \frac{-1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \ln(X_{i})$$

To take the expectation of this estimator, what's the next step? I believe that I need to find the underlying distribution for $\theta$, correct?

---

I ask that question, only because a solution does not find this underlying distribution (or else is not explicit):

[image]

---

And what if I find $\theta$ to be $(1 - \bar{X})/\bar{X}$?

In that case, how would I find the underlying pmf of $\theta$?

Comment: The 'solution' finds $E(\ln X)$ without finding the pdf of $X$. From there you ought to be able to find the expectation of the MLE ($\hat \theta,$ not $\theta$) as originally specified. Beyond that it is unclear to me what you are asking. Can you clarify exactly what you are asked to do or what you are exploring? (And make sure to distinguish notation between a parameter and its estimate.)

Comment: Normally when I think of finding $\mathbb{E}[X]$, I think intuitively that "we're just summing together $f(x) * x$, for all $x$ in the space." I was under the impression that for the estimator $\hat{\theta}$, there is, similarly, a range of values that $\hat{\theta}$ can take on -- and each value has a probability.

Comment: This range and probability is implicit, I guess, in the solution above?